# Get Value of JTextField Changed

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, temperature, valuechangelistener

I am making a small java Swing Applet that converts temperatures: TempConvert.java

Here is my code:

```
package swing;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

/** Celcius to Fahrenheit Converter
 * @version 1.0
 * @author Oliver Ni
 */

public class TempConvert extends JApplet{
    JLabel result;
    JRadioButton ctof;
    JRadioButton ftoc;
    JTextField deg;
    JLabel degLab;
    JButton convert;

    public void convert() {
        if (ctof.isSelected() == true) {
            result.setText("<html><br>" + Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(deg.getText()) * 9 / 5 + 32) + "<sup>o</sup> F</html>");
        } else if (ftoc.isSelected() == true) {
            result.setText("<html><br>" + Integer.toString((Integer.parseInt(deg.getText()) - 32) * 5 / 9) + "<sup>o</sup> C</html>");
        } else {
            result.setText("<html><br>Error.</html>");
        }
    }

    public void makeApplet() {
        setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        ctof = new JRadioButton("Celcius to Fahrenheit");
        ftoc = new JRadioButton("Fahrenheit to Celcius");
        convert = new JButton("Convert");
        result = new JLabel("");
        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        group.add(ctof);
        group.add(ftoc);

        deg = new JTextField(10);
        degLab = new JLabel("<html><sup>o</sup></html>");
        convert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
                convert();
            }
        });
        add(ctof);
        add(ftoc);
        add(deg);
        add(degLab);
        add(convert);
        add(result);
    }

    public void init() {
        try {
            SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    makeApplet();
                }
            });
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error loading because " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

I want to call the `convert()` function every time the text in the `JTextField` `deg` is changed. Is there any way I can do that?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You've already added an ActionListener to your convert button -- isn't that all you need to do?

Comment: Is this an assignment? And if so, do you have specific requirements? And if so, please post them, as well as your code attempt to solve the current issue. If this were my program, the first thing I'd do would be to make it more robust: allow double numeric entry, use a JFormattedTextField to only allow numeric entry, and then pretty up the GUI layouts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to add listener to textfield. Add following snippet and it should work.

```
deg.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        convert();
    }
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        convert();
    }
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
        convert();
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 Add the null checks. for when you remove and change and there is no text. To avoid nullpointer

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have an ActionListener attached to your convert button.  You need to implement the same ActionListener for the JTextField `deg`

Or you code try so that when you get an event for the textfield you post an event to the button using `postActionEvent`